Is there any way to use 'Blender Texel Density Checker Addon' within geometry nodes?
trying to calculate density on some UVs to scale. is there any way to use Blender-Texel-Density-Checker within nodes?  I noticed it within some shader nodes but was unable work out how.
https://github.com/mrven/Blender-Texel-Density-Checker/

Can you bake it to a texturw and then sample the texturw?
